# How to send Control Change Messages MSB and LSB to select bank?

Tags: c#, uwp, midi

I am using UWP Midi in my application to control my Yamaha MOX8 keyboard. I am able to send ProgramChangeMessages to change the patches on my keyboard. I am able to change the first 128 patches with a simple Program Change Message. However, there are several banks that have patches I'd like to switch to. According to the Yamaha documentation the first bank, or default bank is labeled PRE1 (MSB=63, LSB=0) and that I need to send a Control Change to change the bank before sending the Program Change.

The next bank is PRE2 (MSB=63, LSB=1). PRE3 (MSB=64,LSB=2), PRE4 (MSB=63,LSB=3), PRE5 (MSB=63,LSB=4) all the way through USR3 (MSB=63,LSB=10). There is one more bank for GM (MSB=0,LSB=0) and one for DRUMS (MSB=63,LSB=32)

```
    // How do MSB, LSB value translate into the Control Change Message api below?         
    var ccMessage = new MidiControlChangeMessage(Byte Channel, Byte Control, Byte ControlValue);
    midiOutPort.SendMessage(ccMessage);

    // This message works for changing the program patch:
    IMidiMessage midiMessateToSend = new MidiProgramChangeMessage(0, 73);
    midiOutPort.SendMessage(midiMessateToSend);
```

What values should be placed into the Control and ControlValue parameters of the MidiControlChangeMessage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the [MIDI specficiation](https://www.midi.org/specifications/item/the-midi-1-0-specification), or [this reference table](https://www.midi.org/specifications/item/table-3-control-change-messages-data-bytes-2), or page 120 of the Data List manual, the bank select controller has numbers 0/32.
For example, to select "Trojan" (instrument 74 in PRE5) on the first channel:

```
... new MidiControlChangeMessage(0,  0, 63);
... new MidiControlChangeMessage(0, 32,  4);
... new MidiProgramChangeMessage(0,     73);
```